# How to detect the last character

Tags: java, string

I have a string and i want to know if the last character in my string is `#`
**example:**

```
String test="test my String #";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply:

```
if (test.endsWith("#"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet should be instructive:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "asdf#",
        "#asdf",
        "sdf#f",
        "#",
        "",
        "asdf",
    };
    String fmt = "%6s%12s%12s%12s%n";
    System.out.format(fmt, "String", "startsWith", "endsWith", "contains");
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.format(fmt, test,
            test.startsWith("#"),
            test.endsWith("#"),
            test.contains("#")
        );
    }
```

This prints:

```
String  startsWith    endsWith    contains
 asdf#       false        true        true
 #asdf        true       false        true
 sdf#f       false       false        true
     #        true        true        true
             false       false       false
  asdf       false       false       false
```

#### String API links

- [`boolean startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Tests if this string starts with the specified prefix.
- [`boolean endsWith(String suffix)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

  - Tests if this string ends with the specified suffix.
- [`boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

  - Returns `true` if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(test.endsWith("#"))
```

Or, if you really want to do it manually (not a good idea)...

```
if(test.charAt(test.length()-1) == '#')
```

Comment: taht is too late xD I also may be wrong but teh second could do harm for empty strings :(

Comment: Ehrm, charAt returns a char, does it not? So you should a) use `==` instead of `.equals` and b compare to `'#'` instead of `"#"`.

Comment: @Johannes - yeah and thought I was so fast can't compete with him :-/. @sepp2k - yup was a typo fixed it right away you read fast :)